# Woo Lost Password form redirects to wp-admin reauth=1

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, subdomain

In WooCommerce, on `https://shop.example.com/my-account/lost-password/` when I submit a valid user e-mail, I get redirected to the wp-login form.

Specifically with 302 to `https://shop.example.com/wp-admin/`, which then redirects me 302 to `https://shop.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fshop.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` (I watch it in devtools network tab).

Entering a wrong e-mail works and gives error message.

I've tested that the nonce gets validated in `class-wc-form-handler.php`.

Any ideas of reasons for this?

My WooCommerce is running on a subdomain, using Multidomain plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce redirects using `wp_safe_redirect`, which checks for `allowed_redirect_hosts`. These can be added as in [this blogpost](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/allowed-domains-in-safe-redirects.html):

```
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', 'misha_extend_allowed_domains_list' );
 
function misha_extend_allowed_domains_list( $hosts ){
 
    $hosts[] = 'example.com';
    $hosts[] = 'shop.example.com';
 
    return $hosts;
 
}
```